# Find all finite sets A that has some property

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all finite sets A such that $x^3-3\left|x\right|+4 \in A$ for all $x \in A$.

I have tried to find the smallest element of A by solving $a^3-3\left|a\right|+4\geq a$ with $a$ being the smallest element but I didn't make any further progress.

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-3|x|+4$.

For $x\le 0$, 
$$f(x)=x^3+3x+4=x+(x^3+2x+4),$$ 
where the part in parentheses is strictly increasing from $-\infty$ to $+4$.
We conclude that there is exactly one $x_0\in(-\infty,0]$ with $f(x_0)=x_0$, and that $f(x)<x$ for $x<x_0$, $f(x)>x$ for $x_0<x\le 0$.

For $x>0$, 
$f(x)-x=x^3-4x+4$ has derivative $f'(x)=3x^2-4$, hence a local extremum (in fact, a minimum) at $x_1=\frac2{\sqrt 3}$, where $f(x_1)-x_1=x_1^3-4x_1+4=4-\frac{16}9\sqrt 3>0$. We conclude that $f(x)>x$ for all $x> 0$.

In summary,

> $$\tag1f(x)\gtreqless x\iff x\gtreqless x_0.$$

Let $A$ be a non-empty finite set with $f(x)\in A$ for all $x\in A$. By this,  $\min A\le f(\min A)$ and $\max A\ge f(\max A)$. Then with $(1)$, it follows that $\min A\ge x_0\ge \max A\ge min A$, hence equality throughout.

We conclude that the only finite sets $A$ with the desired property are
$$A=\emptyset\qquad\text{and}\qquad A=\{x_0\}. $$